# Put across vs get across

Tags: comparison

I'd like to ask if these two words are interchangeable ?

**put something ↔ across phrasal verb**

1   to explain your ideas, beliefs etc in a way that people can understand:

2  put yourself across  British English to explain your ideas and opinions clearly so that people understand them and realize what sort of person you are:

> He was trying to put across a serious point.
>
> Sue's never been very good at putting herself across at interviews.
>
> Television can be a useful way of putting across health messages

**get something ↔ across**
to succeed in communicating an idea or piece of information to someone, or to be communicated successfully

> It took him ages to get his point across.
>
> We must get across the simple fact that drugs are dangerous.
>
> I was trying to get across how much I admired them.
>
> It is important that we get this message across to voters.
>
> What message are you trying to get across to the consumer?

Source : Longman and McMillan Dictionary

Comment: The (relatively small) difference is encapsulated in the first two words of your two definitions. To ***put*** something across primarily implies you ***put your explanation out there*** (you ***explained*** it in words), whereas to ***get*** it across also implies ***the explanation was received and understood*** (you ***succeeded*** in communicating).

Comment: Edge case: *I **put** my idea across at the meeting, but they didn't understand it* is a perfectly ordinary conjunction of two "compatible" concepts, but it wouldn't really make sense to say *I **got** my idea across at the meeting, but they didn't understand it*.

Comment: Precisely *because* it's primarily an AmE usage in this context, I think it's better that an AmE speaker should post an actual answer. (Who knows? Perhaps they might not even *agree* with my UK perspective.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FumbleFingers has pointed out

> **to put across** an idea (AmE)
>   **to put forward** an idea (BrE)

is to suggest or present an idea.

Also a standard BrE phrase is

> I **put** it to you that...

which also has the meaning "here's an example", "take for example"

> **to get across** an idea (AmE, BrE)
>   *to make them understand, to get them to understand*

is to have the suggested idea understood.

> We weren't able to **get across** that going out in a storm was a bad idea.
>   In our pitch, we **got across** to the Board that increase advertising will increase sales.

A related phrase **get through** can have the same meaning as **get across**

> What we are trying to **get through** to you is that this is very important.
>   *What we are trying to get across is that this is very important*
>
> "You might understand if I could ever **get through** that thick skull of yours." he said in exasperation.